# Prove set of matrices with eigenvalue $1$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, matrices, continuity

The idea of this question is to find a continuous map onto a closed set, then take the preimage of that closed set to show that a particular set is closed.

I'm stumped on this one question: Show the set of all $n \times n$ with all eigenvalues equal to $1$ is closed.

What kinds of maps can I consider?

Comment: Note that the statement only works if you count complex eigenvalues.  For example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&2&-1/n \\ 0&1/n&2 \end{bmatrix}$ has 1 as its only real eigenvalue for each $n$, while the limit of this sequence of matrices has real eigenvalues 1 and 2.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think that the hypotesis is: the matrix has $n$ eigenvalues, all equal to $1$

Comment: The only $n \times n$ matrix with eigenvalue 1 of multiplicity $n$ is the identity matrix so that would be trivial.  If what you mean is that 1 is a *generalized* eigenvalue of multiplicity $n$, then yes, it works - but IMO that's getting a bit stretched as an interpretation of the statement, as opposed to my interpretation that 1 is the only complex eigenvalue.  (And yes, I know they're equivalent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the map 
\begin{gather}
f:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R})\\
f(A) = (A-I)^n
\end{gather}
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then your space is $f^{-1}(0)$ and so it is closed.

The map works because all engenvalues equal to one means that $A-I$ is nilpotent.

Comment: one inclusion is easy but why $A-I$ nilpotent imply all eigenvalues of $A$ are 1?

Comment: If $A-I$ nilpotent, then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $(t-1)^n$; then $A$ has only $1$ as eingenvalue

Answer (score 0):

For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ let $$\gamma_i=\text {sum of principal minors of order }i\text { for }1 \le i \le n.$$ Define $f:M_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by
$$f(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\gamma_i-{n \choose i})^2.$$ Then $f(A)=0$ iff $\gamma_i={n \choose i}$ for $1 \le i \le n$ iff $\det(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda -1)^n$. Thus $f^{-1}(0)$ is the set of matrices for which all eigenvalues are 1.

Comment: Probably I have a different definition of _principal minors_ : for me a principal minor of the matrix $A$ (of order $i$) is the determinant of a submatrix of $A$ realized taking $i$ rows and columns with same indices. But if you take the matrix $\left[\begin{matrix} -2 & -3\\ 3 & 4 \end{matrix}\right]$ it has all eingenvalues $1$ but $\gamma_1 = -2+4 = 2 \neq 1$.

Comment: @Menzio: I have corrected the post so that the sum of the principal minors of order i is nCi, which is the coefficient in (\lambda-1)^n

Comment: @sedrick:,@Daniel Schlepler:,@Caffeine:,@-infinity: Please see my corrected post.